# How to use a forval loop and take into account one exception?

Tags: stata

I have `900` files that include `1,000` variables named v1 – v1000 and `1` file that includes `43` variables named v1 – v43.

My code in Stata initially opens each file using a `foreach` loop that imports the files while erasing the first line for each file (not shown here).

Then, I use this nested `forval` loop to rename variables:

```
forval j = 1/1000 { 
    local varname = strtoname(v`j'[1])  
    rename v`j' x`varname' 
}
```

This code doesn’t work well because my last file doesn’t have the variables named v44 – v1000.

I need a code snippet that can read `1,000` variables for the first `900` files and `43` variables for the last file. I tried with `c(k)` (i.e. counting the number of variables in each file before looping):

```
forval j = 1/ `c(k)' {
    local varname = strtoname(v`j'[1]) 
    rename v`j'  x`varname'
}
```

However, this doesn’t work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A very easy, not very elegant method would be to check whether the variable exists with `capture`:

```
foreach dta in `allfiles' {
    use `dta', clear
    forval j = 1/1000 { 
         local varname = strtoname(v`j'[1])  
         cap confirm variable v`j'
         if (_rc == 0) rename v`j' x`varname' 
    }
    save `dta', replace
}
```

Comment: `confirm variable` exists for precisely this purpose.

Comment: @NickCox not sure why you upvoted this. The loop will not work because there are no 1000 variables in 1 file but across 901 files.

Comment: I get _rc == 0 for an existing variable and 111 if the variable does not exist.

Comment: Still easier to go `foreach v of var v*`. and rewrite the loop in terms of local  `v`.